# Best practice when create a subset of data in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What would be considered best practice when working with the following scenario?

I have a dataset of ~6 million records total, broken down into 30+ tables with some tables having a few hundred thousand records.  I need to use an api that only allows an insert of 200 records at a time.

I am breaking down the insert by table. Now here is where I am considering the first two options that came to my mind.  I can either get the full dataset for that table and then in C# loop through the dataset only inserting 200 at a time.  Or I can make multiple database calls grabbing 200 records at a time. Creating my object and making the call to the API to insert my records. Which I think I could make the next database call while the other records are being inserted.

Comment: If these tables are totally independent, you could divide and conquer on this and do multiple inserts at once to different tables on different threads. But it's difficult to really say without seeing all your schema. If you need to insert 6 million rows and do 200 at a time and do separate calls to the DB, that's going to be 30,000 different calls, which seems excessive to me.

Comment: You could set the DataAdapter's [`UpdateBatchSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize(v=vs.110).aspx) to 200.

Comment: Why are you calling the database from C# and then inserting that many rows back into the database? Could this be done all from within SQL or maybe using SSIS, or is there a UI component to this?

Comment: Explain more about the target environment, this 200-record restriction, and whether there are restrictions on asynchronous calls and simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple threads, with each reading and inserting 200 at a time.  Not only will this be faster, but you won't run into potential [OutOfMemoryExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) with that large of a dataset by being unable to allocate contiguous blocks over fragmented memory.

Comment: Thank you hyru!  I was leaning towards something like this but like Michael said in the comments that leads towards a lot of data calls.

Comment: Since this is the route I am going down thought I would offer these to links to anybody that will be doing the same.

There is a lot of good information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177488/c-sharp-threading)

And I went [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) first